# how to display a different text boolean json

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

In my json file I have boolean and I want to display different texts if it's true or false
example: if true show 'yes' else show 'no' in html.

I hope I was clear

thank you

**json.file**

```
 {
        "boatType": "Semi-rigide",
        "img": "/assets/img/boat-img/semi-rigide.jpg",
        "longeur": 10,
        "largeur": 20,
        "tirantEau": 50,
        "equipage": false,
        "annexe": true
    },
```

**component.ts**

```
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  user: IBoat[] = [];

  constructor(private boatService: BoatService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.boatService.getBoat()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.user = data
      });
  }
}
```

**html**

```
 <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let boat of user">
            <td data-label="img"><img [src]="boat.img" alt="boat" class="img"></td>
            <td data-label="longeur">{{boat.longeur}} cm</td>
            <td data-label="largeur">{{boat.largeur}} cm</td>
            <td data-label="tirant d'eau">{{boat.tirantEau}} cm</td>
            <td data-label="equipage">{{boat.equipage}}</td>
            <td data-label="annexe">{{boat.annexe}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Try changing `{{boat.annexe}}` to `{{boat.annexe ? "yes" : "no"}}`

Answer (score 0):

First create a variable called jsonData in your json file:

```
jsonData =  {
        "boatType": "Semi-rigide",
        "img": "/assets/img/boat-img/semi-rigide.jpg",
        "longeur": 10,
        "largeur": 20,
        "tirantEau": 50,
        "equipage": false,
        "annexe": true
    }
```

Then reference the json file in your script tag in the head

```
<head>
<!-- Other code -->
<script src="file.json">
 
</head>
```

Then parse the json

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(jsonData)
```

Now you seem a little vague around this part which variable you are checking if true/false so I'll provide code for the two booleans.

```
parsed.equipage ? console.log("yes") : console.log("No")
// other code
parsed.annexe ? console.log("yes") : console.log("no")
```

If you wanted to change directly an element's text on the page simply do

```
document.getElementById("id").innerText = "Yes"
```

And substitute for `console.log()`if you wish.

If I have misinterpreted the question just say
Hope this answer helped you :)